# Why does this reversed for loop miss the last item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to reverse loop through a table and join the table items to make a string. This code works fine but it misses the last item of the table :

```
 t = [0, 0, 2, 6, 14, 4, 7, 0]
 for i in range(len(t) - 1, 0, -1):
     res = str(t[i]) + res
 return res
```

It prints `02614470` instead of `002614470`.

I know if I change `0` to `-1` in the loop parameter it would work properly but I want to understand why. It seems that when I want to use -1 as step, the middle parameter (0 in this case ) adds +1. So for example if I want the loop to stop at index 1 I have to write 0 in the parameter. Is that right?

That's my thought process but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: `range` does not include its right bound, that's all. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Comment: i dont understand why the bound reaches 1 if i type 0 so basically it reaches the bound +1 when the step is negative and the opposite  is true ?

Comment: Why don’t you print `i` in the loop then you can see exactly what indexes are being used.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I've done that when the bound is 0 the index reaches 1 and the stop so can you please get to the point and stop sending me these links it just want to know if my thought process is correct  or not it a simple yes or no if you want you don't have to explain

Comment: I think we're just confused. You already have the solution. I'm confused why you elected to ask a question on StackOverflow instead of trying the idea you had and seeing if it worked. What happens when you put -1 as the argument?

Answer (score 2):

The typical construction of a for loop with range() is:

```
t=[0,0,2,6,14,4,7,0]
for i in range(0,len(t)):
    print(f"{i}, {t[i]}")
```

This makes sense to iterate through a list of items which starts at zero and is len() long. Since we start at zero, we have to stop at one less than the value returned for len(t), so range() is built to accommodate this most common case. As you noted in your case, since you are reversing this you would have to iterate through and use a -1 to capture the zero'th index in the list. Fortunately, you can use the following syntax to reverse the range, which leads to better readability:

```
t=[0,0,2,6,14,4,7,0]
for i in reversed(range(0,len(t))):
    print(f"{i}, {t[i]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in the range is a **stop** value so it is excluded from  the generation.

for example, when you do `range(10)`, Python processes this as `range(0,10)` and yields values 0,1,2,...,7,8,9 (i.e. not 10)

Going in reverse, if you want zero to be included, you have to set the stop value at the next lower value past zero (i.e. -1)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained that `range` does not include the end number. It always stops one short of the end, whether the range is forward or backward.

I'd like to add some more "Pythonic" ways to write the loop. As a rule of thumb try to avoid looping over list *indices* and instead loop over the *items* directly.

```
things = [...]

# Forward over items
for thing in things:
    print(thing)

# Backward over items
for thing in reversed(things):
    print(thing)
```

If you want the indices use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). It attaches indices to each item so you can loop over both at the same time. No need for `range` or `len`.

```
# Forward over items, with indices
for i, thing in enumerate(things):
    print(i, thing)

# Backward over items, with indices
for i, thing in reversed(enumerate(things)):
    print(i, thing)
```